# countdown not working properly

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

The following script is for countdown timer, but on page refresh it again starts from beginning. Can anyone suggest me the solution for the same?
I changed everything but failed, can anyone suggest me what to do with it?

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
    }

    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Comment: Use localStorage if you want to store the elapsed time

Comment: use window.localStorage.setItem('testKey','store the timer value'); and store the timer value and to get the value on page load to start from it.
window.localStorage.getItem('testKey')

Comment: Please someone help me with code

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing any data in user's browser, so everything is cleared after page refresh. To get rid of this problem you can do few things:

1. Use local storage -> you can store something as a string here, It would be the best, but not the easier(?) way to do that.
2. Use cookies -> same as above
3. Session storage -> this may not work as expected on all browsers.
4. Save data in some kind of database. This one will be hardest to implement, but will allow you to easier extend functionality of timer in future.

Comment: Can you please illustrate me with the exact code, i am a newbie to this.